# CMake error "Can't link to the standard math library"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker, cmake

While trying to configure my c++ project using CMake I was faced with the following error message:

> The C compiler identification is unknown
>   The CXX compiler identification is unknown
>   CMake Error at nestk/deps/eigen/CMakeLists.txt:71 (message):
>     Can't link to the standard math library.  Please report to the Eigen
>     developers, telling them about your platform.
>   Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Has anyone a hint of how to fix this problem?

Any help is much appreciated.

I'm using: Windows 7 x64, CMake 2.8.10.2, VS2010 Ultimate

Comment: Are you running cmake from a *Visual Studio* command prompt?

Comment: Also did you pick the "Visual Studio 10 Win64" generator?

Comment: I am neither running cmake from the Visual Studio promt (I am working with the CMake-gui) nor choosing  the "Visual Studio 10 Win64" generator (I took "Visual Studio 10" as the generator).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because

```
#include <cmath>
```

does not compile on your machine.  You will have to get this on your path to get around the standard math library error (I am working in ubuntu, but I had to install the gcc compiler).  Try compiling and running this program:

```
#include<cmath>
#include<iostream>
int main() { std::cout << std::sin(0.0) << std::endl; std::cout << std::log(0.0f) << std::endl; }
```

Once you can do that, then make sure to remove the build directory you were running cmake in and try to build again.